# How close button in ubuntu works on clicking?

Tags: 16.10, button

Can any one tell when I click X button of any application how it works?

Comment: It closes the application.

Comment: I want to know how it works at the back end, which script runs that closes the window.

Comment: There is no script or command. The code is built into the OS and the application as @WardTruyen says in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to see this.

First is the easy way:
It closes the window. If it's the last window or the main window of a program the program will be closed too.

Then in a longer sense of how does it works:
When you click your mouse the mouse will send a mouse down signal to your PC, the OS will catch it. Analyze the position of your mouse(in this case hovering over the X of a window) witch is dependent on the Software installed (Unity is drawing your X on a standard install of LTS Ubuntu) so it has a way of interacting with that software and ask what is under the mouse at point. The software will return with the message that it should close the window. Then the OS will transmit that to the program. After that the program should check it's OS messages, notice this close message and decide what to do. It will probably close the window, maybe close the program and maybe show something like a "save data?" or "close tabs?"-dialogue first.

This last part, where the message is transferred from the OS to the program is fully described here: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html#Overview_of_the_X_Window_System

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know when I am clicking the cross button of my browser how it is closing the program, what command or script is running to close the program.

Comment: No command or script is involved in pressing the close button. I would advise to take another approach if you want to change these buttons. Check out some Desktop Environments(DE) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface). Maybe there's a way/DE that adds the stuff you're looking for.